# Tap to tweet/tap to post is at the bottom of the notification center

Tags: ios, twitter

On iOS 6 on my iPhone the tap to tweet/tap to post buttons are located on the bottom of the notification center causing me to either have to scroll down or clear some messages before I can see them.

On my iPad it is on the top, which makes me think that is where it should also be on my iPhone. Is this normal expected behavior or has something gone wrong with my phone?

Any possible fixes would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the **Notifications** section of the Settings app, you can tap the **Edit** button in the upper right to make handles appear (three thick horizontal lines) on each of the items  in Notification Center.

[image] [image]

You can drag the items up or down by these handles to re-order them, so just drag the **Share Widget** item to the top, if that's where you want it, then tap done.

Comment: I can't believe I have never noticed that before! Thanks for the simple solution, you have no idea what all I have tried doing to remedy the problem!

Comment: The reordering for apps was introduced in iOS 5, but I think being able to reposition the built-in items (i.e. weather and sharing) is new in iOS 6.